# How can I convert UTF-8 characters to a string?

Tags: c#, html, utf-8, converters

The following url :

> http://www.thecage.co.il/online_users.json.js?r=

Responds with a string with some strange characters (you can browse and see)
I am trying to convert it to a real string (I know it supposed to be in Hebrew).

My code:

```
string html = client.DownloadString(SITE_URL).Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. Some Hebrew that, that's all.

Comment: don't you see something like {"UserName":"××•×¨×™××Ÿ", ? @Oded

Comment: Nope. I see things like `ורוניק` (Veronique) in Hebrew. Take a look at your browser language settings for that page.

Comment: Please post the code you are using to fetch the information.

Comment: The resource doesn't send charset header so it depends on the browser default encoding. If your browser's default encoding isn't the correct one (UTF-8), you will see garbage for some characters.

Comment: I use System.Net.WebClient in order to get the response... maybe that's the problem?

Comment: I'm on Chrome 22 and I get `{"UserName":"××•×¨×™××Ÿ".....` everywhere too. Not voting to close, can't see why people are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the webclient's encoding to UTF-8:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string html = client.DownloadString(SITE_URL).Replace("\"", string.Empty);
```